# Google shows indexes of non-existing hacked-like URLs of my site and cached to other pages

Tags: account-security

Today I tried site:mysite.com at google and noticed that I have pages indexed with urls that shouldn't be there for example **instead of**

```
mysite.com/item/123/apple_wifi_review
```

I have:

```
mysite.com/item/123/children.Also
```

This page goes to the item number 123 on my site anyway but I wonder where has google got this url.

To make it worse I can see this url on google:

```
mysite.com/redirectUrl.php?elementId=494
```

Which if I click goes to "not found page" on my site but google **cache** show a page belonging to another site.

Comment: Not sure if there is a question here? What are you asking? How to remove the URLs? If so check google web tools out to manage your domain with google.

Comment: Have you done a check on your domain's history? What is the date on the Google cache site? It sounds like it was once owned by another entity and these URLs might of been live long ago. You can remove these URLs with Google's web master tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one other possibility (other than what's mentioned by @bacon-brad):

Hackers don't always deface the site they hack.

It is possible that your site was once hacked and cached from that time. Redirection is not unusual when hacked (even today) and serves multiple purposes ranging from drive-by downloads to malicious ads to click-fraud.
If you've recreated / done major changes to your site since the hack-time, it explains you seeing "page not found" on your site but a cached site points somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Sas3. This seems to be true in my case. It seems that my site was hacked months ago and since I recently revamped everything I see this peculiar problem.